# Sample size calculators

Tags: statistical-power

Background: I understand the formulae and manipulations below. My question refers much more to rules of thumb for which I have very little knowledge or experience

If I were to build a sample size calculator I would write something similar to what is described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117372/where-to-read-about-how-to-build-a-sample-size-calculator-for-power-analysis-for)

This is the same process that is followed by [this](https://github.com/heliosdrm/pwr/blob/master/R/pwr.2p.test.R) R function.

A key feature of such a calculation is that a proportion of 0.5 leads to the largest standard deviation and is thus used to calculate a worst case sample size (if the baseline proportion is unknown)

For this reason I am confused with what is happening with [this](http://www.adobe-target.com/testcalculator.html) calculator. Specifically, the third and fourth rows of the table, when varying the baseline order rate field.

At 95% significance and 80% power, why does a 90% baseline need a sample size of 550 (per test variation) and a 10% baseline need a sample size of 57760? Surely the p*(1-p) means that these values should be the same?

I think there might be something built in to do with making sure there are enough successes in the sample, but I can't work it out and the html is not clear?

I've posted this here and not on SO because I'm assuming its a sample size calculation methodology that I have not heard about.